# $G\times H$ is not a simple group for $|G|, |H|\geq 2$

Tags: group-theory, proof-verification, normal-subgroups, simple-groups

I would appreciate if you could please express your opinion about my proof and maybe give me a hint where you deem suitable.

*Proof:*

Define a homomorphism as follows $\phi: (G\times H)\to G$ by $\phi[(g,h)]=g$. We then show that this homomorphism is well-defined (omitted).

Now, for any $(e, h) \in G\times H$, $\phi[(e,h)]=e$. Therefore, $\ker\phi$ is not trivial. But $\ker\phi$ is a normal subgroup of $G\times H$. Therefore, $G\times H$ is not simple.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that both $H,G$ are normal in $H\times G$: $$(h,g)(h',1)(h^{-1},g^{-1}) = (hh'h^{-1},gg^{-1})=({}^hh',1)\in H\times 1$$The same works for $1\times G$.

Comment: Do you think my proof might be acceptable too?

Comment: @sequence The idea of your proof is fine. You need to prove that such map is a group morphism and that its kernel is $H$, and you're done.

Comment: Why do we need to show that $\ker\phi=H$?